# Postgres SQL Check for duplicate records before inserting

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to know what is the optimal approach for inserting a duplicate record.  I am using Postgres. I am trying **2** approaches and have timing metrics on the results but I would like to know which is best or if there is another way.

1. Perform `INSERT` then if there is a duplicate key exception, I handle
   that.
2. Before performing `INSERT` do a `SELECT`, if the record exists I will
   not perform the `INSERT`.

I feel approach **1** is best as there is only one request to the `DB` but if there are many duplicates then approach **1** is quite slow, due to the duplicate key exception handling I assume.

In my use case, I am expecting round `3-4%` duplicates.

Comment: Why not simply use `insert on conflict`?

Comment: Can you give an example.  Here is my current:   INSERT INTO  objects (org, space, participant) VALUES ('584cf4cd-eea7-4c8c-83ee-67d88fc6eab5', 'aeb08f71-710c-43c2-b62e-5a644925316e', 'fa56e002-ff83-11e7-99ae-a1d83457a777')

Comment: Just add `on conflict do nothing` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT

Comment: INSERT INTO objects (org, space, participant) VALUES ('584cf4cd-eea7-4c8c-83ee-67d88fc6eab5', 'aeb08f71-710c-43c2-b62e-5a644925316e', 'fa56e002-ff83-11e7-99ae-a1d83457a777')  ON CONFLICT      getting org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException

Comment: you may refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-to-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql

Comment: `on conflict do nothing` **not** `on conflict`

Comment: Excellent comments thanks,  I am using postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.4.17  so I need to upgrade to > 9.5  then I will use  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING

Comment: If you go through the work to upgrade, you should go straight to v10 (or wait 2 weeks an upgrade to v11)

Comment: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint objects   when I tried to use "ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING"